# Как сделать "обертку" на php для занесения блока html кода в переменную?

Tags: php

Шаблон декоратор позволяет нам обернуть что-то.

У меня возник такой вопрос.

**А есть ли решение (паттерн, подход) для того, чтобы загнать в переменную код страницы, который находится между некими "маркерами"?**

Т.е. по сути повторить функционал Heredoc синтаксиса, но не встроенным средством в php.

Что-то хочется такого плана (желательно без ООП, но можно и предложить небольшое ООП решение):

```
beginBlock($variable);
<h1>Example...</h1>
<div><?= $needCount ? $object->countRows : '' ?></div>
...
endBlock($variable);
```

Только не спрашивайте "А зачем?". Бывает нужно. Например, когда внутри html блока сложные вычисления, а движек старый и реализован функциональным программированием (без ООП). Почему не подходит Heredoc? Бывает не устраивает(дает некий дискомфорт) из-за некоторых IDE или по другим причинам.

**Еще раз - не надо пытаться меня сделать хорошим кодером. Я прекрасно использую в жизни ООП. Есть просто вопрос - нужен просто ответ. Без философии.**

Даже если незачем - просто интересно знать.

Если есть подобные решения - намекните ссылкой или примером.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ob_start();

Тут любой код PHP, осуществляющий какой-то вывод

$variable = ob_get_clean();
```

[Функции контроля вывода](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.outcontrol.php)

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85acd5436826e8318226ff553e491365d9a6911a)

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(){
    ?>
        <span>bar</span>
    <?
}
foo();
```

**Крайне нерекомендуемый метод**, однако. Можно хранить темплейты в тех же XML, и разворачивать функцией на php в html. А "бывает нужно" - когда "не хочется делать нормально". Это с треском подойдет даже для разовых решений проблем, ибо существенно, просто в разы, ухудшает читаемость кода, умножает на ноль его гибкость и функциональность, изобилует закрывающими/открывающими тегами php, и вообще моветон.

Comment: хранить можно в чем угодно (: но если вам дан старый проект где куча каши html+php... и вам нужно часть "каши" вынести для повторного использования - не представляется нормальным сидеть и выносить эти шедевры куда либо. там и так все работает еле еле) + люди привыкли править такие-то файлы в таком то месте. тут как раз вариант взять это в переменную маркерами и вставить куда мне надо. рефакторинг там уже не поможет

Comment: Даже не могу представить себе ситуацию, когда невозможно было бы написать простейший парсер/шаблонизатор, который либо через темплейты, либо банальным вызовом пользовательских функций вывода элементов создавал страницу. На этой уйдет от силы пара часов, было бы желание %)